# Java byte array manipulation

Tags: java, arrays, one-time-password

I am trying to select the lower 4 bits of the last byte in a byte array. This is how I have previously done it in PHP but I am new to Java.

```
$lower4bit = substr($bytes[19], -1);

//Convert the hex to decimal to get the offset value
$offset = hexdec($lower4bit);

//Select the value of the 4 bytes starting at the offset
$joinedArray = implode(array_slice($bytes, $offset, 4));
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction with Java?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but keep in mind... in PHP an 'array' is array, list, map, and all kinds of other stuff. In Java, they're not all rolled into one.

Comment: This is very wrong way to do it even in PHP though. `$lower4bit = $bytes[19] & 0x0F;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access an array like so:

```
y = a[i];
```

You find the length of an array like so:

```
len = a.length;
```

You can isolate the last 4 bits of an integer like so:

```
y = x & 0xF;
```

These should be sufficient to construct the code that you need.

Comment: Thanks. I follow the first two, thats great. I now have the last byte. Not sure how the third bit works though. What does the 0xF do?

Comment: @Joseph: The final statement is applying a [bitmask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmask).  `0xF` is a hexadecimal constant with the 4 lsbs set.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I am getting it: usage of a [bitmask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmask) comes in handy.  But where does the x come from?

Comment: @fuzzy - I think I was just using that to stand for an arbitrary variable/expression.